# "with any truth"

Tags: expressions

> "Undoubtedly, she was kind, but even her best friend could not say, with any truth, that she was physically attractive."

I understand the general meaning of this sentence, but what does "with any truth" mean?

Answer (score 1):

**"say, with any truth, "** means almost the same thing as **"truthfully say".**

In both cases, the verb "say" is being modified.  "Truthfully" is an adverb doing the modification in "truthfully say".  "with any truth" is a prepositional phrase doing the same thing in "say, with any truth,".

The subtle difference is that "cannot say, with any truth" suggests that there would be *no amount of truth* in the statement.  None at all.  Whereas "cannot say truthfully" could apply to a statement that has 10% truth, or 20% truth.  So the use of "with any truth" in the sentence instead of "truthfully" suggests to the reader that the statement "she is physically attractive" is *really, really, really* not true.